Cohomology of "symplectically self-dual" chain complex
Let $G,H$ be abelian groups (denoted additively) with their Pontryagin duals denoted as $G^*$ and $H^*$. (The cases I'm interested in are products of $\mathbb Z_n$, $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, so feel free to add attributes as long as these examples are covered.)
Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma: H\times H^*&\rightarrow H^*\times H\\
(h,h')&\rightarrow (-h',h)\;.
\end{aligned}
$$
Let
$$S: G\rightarrow H\times H^*$$
be a group homomorphism such that
$$S^*\sigma S=0\;.$$
Then consider the middle homology group $H_1$ of the length-2 chain complex
$$G\xrightarrow{\sigma S} H\times H^*\xrightarrow{S^*} G^*\;.$$
Question: Is it true that $H_1$ is always isomorphic to $L\times L^*$ for some abelian group $L$? If yes, what is $L$?
Bonus question: $\sigma$ defines a $U(1)$-valued bilinear form on $H\times H^*$.
This form vanishes on the image of $S$ or $\sigma S$, and thus yields a bilinear form on $H_1$. Is there an isomorphism $H_1\simeq L\times L^*$ such that the bilinear form on $H_1\simeq L\times L^*$ has the same form as $\sigma$ with $L$ instead of $H$?

At least in the finite group case, the answer to your questions is yes, but not for a good reason. Namely, the nondegenerate alternating form on $H \times H^*$ induced by $\sigma$ descends to $H_1$, where it remains alternating and nondegenerate. On the other hand, every finite group with a nondegenerate alternating form does split as $L \times L^*$ for some Lagrangian subgroup $L$ with transverse Lagrangian $L^*$. This is proven for example in Lemma 5.2 of Alexei Davydov, Twisted automorphisms of group algebras, 2007; we review Davydov's proof in 3.2 of Theo Johnson-Freyd and Matthew Yu, Topological Orders in (4+1)-Dimensions, 2021.
But see Davydov's paper for examples showing that this $L$ is not particularly canonical, and not every Lagrangian works. Note that it matters that I'm working with alternating, as opposed to antisymmetric, forms. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ admits a nondegenerate "anti"symmetric form but certainly does not factor as $L \times L^*$ for any subgroup $L$.

Thanks for this! Do you believe this result could generalize to groups like $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$?

On the other hand, it's not clear that any abelian group with non-degenerate alternating form would arise as some $H_1$ like in my question, right? So even if there are examples for infinite abelian groups with non-degenerate alternating forms that do not split as $L\times L^*$, that wouldn't necessarily mean the answer to my question is no?

@AndiBauer I just haven't thought about Lagrangian splittings for general groups, only the finite case. I agree, it could be your case is special. But I don't think it is too special. I tried to work out an example showing that in your case, still the Lagrangian splitting was not canonical, but I couldn't do it in my head. Anyway, I suspect that something like $H = \mathbb{Z}/p^2 = H^*$ (with pairing $\langle a,b\rangle = \exp(2\pi i ab/p^2)$ and $G =  \mathbb{Z}/p$ mapping to $(p,p)$ will show that your question is nontrivial.
